# Find Elementary Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find an elementary matrix **E** such that **AE** = **B**

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}*E=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

There should only be 1 elementary row operation performed on **A**. Scaling either row or swapping either row would not result in **B**, but I am unsure how to solve the specific pivot row operation that is used to obtain **B**.

Comment: The *only* matrix $C$ such that $AC=B$ would be $C=A^{-1}B$, whether $C$ happened to be an elementary matrix or not.

Comment: Yes, I have the textbook answer (1 -3, 0 1)

Comment: @JMoravitz that method would not work for CA = B right?

Comment: If $CA=B$ then by right multiplication by $A^{-1}$ you get $C=BA^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Since the matrix $E$ appears on the right of matrix $A$, think of elementary column operation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Normally, one would use $E=A^{-1}B$ where $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of matrix $A$. Alternatively, we may let
$$
E=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence one would have
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 2a+4c & 2b+4d \\ a+6c & b+6d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
There rest should be easy peasy.

Answer (score 2):

Think of getting $B$ from $A$ (it is a column operation):
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \stackrel{-3\cdot C1+C2\to C2}{\Rightarrow} \begin{bmatrix}2 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=B.$$
Now do the same column operation with unit matrix:
$$I=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \stackrel{-3\cdot C1+C2\to C2}{\Rightarrow} \begin{bmatrix}1 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=E.$$
Verify:
$$AE=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 \\ 1 & 6 \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=B.$$